# com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'akka.stream' when running jar file

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to run an Akka stream application, but get an exception when running on linux.

When I run it with Windows debugger it is working.

I tried both these commands:

```
java -jar ./myService.jar -Dconfig.resource=/opt/myservice/conf/application.conf
java -jar ./myService.jar -Dconfig.file=/opt/myService/conf/application.conf
```

But I get the following exception:

> No configuration setting found for key 'akka.stream'

My `application.conf` file:

```
akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    actor {
        debug {
            # enable function of LoggingReceive, which is to log any received message 
            at
            # DEBUG level
            receive = on
        }
    }

    stream {
        # Default materializer settings
        materializer {
            max-input-buffer-size = 16

            dispatcher = ""

            subscription-timeout {
                mode = cancel
                timeout = 5s
            }

            # Enable additional troubleshooting logging at DEBUG log level
            debug-logging = off

            # Maximum number of elements emitted in batch if downstream signals large demand
            output-burst-limit = 1000

            auto-fusing = on

            # Those stream elements which have explicit buffers (like mapAsync, mapAsyncUnordered,
            # buffer, flatMapMerge, Source.actorRef, Source.queue, etc.) will preallocate a fixed
            # buffer upon stream materialization if the requested buffer size is less than this
            max-fixed-buffer-size = 1000000000

            sync-processing-limit = 1000

            debug {
                fuzzing-mode = off
            }
        }

        blocking-io-dispatcher = "akka.stream.default-blocking-io-dispatcher"

        default-blocking-io-dispatcher {
            type = "Dispatcher"
            executor = "thread-pool-executor"
            throughput = 1

            thread-pool-executor {
                fixed-pool-size = 16
            }
        }
    }

    # configure overrides to ssl-configuration here (to be used by akka-streams, 
    and akka-http – i.e. when serving https connections)
    ssl-config {
        protocol = "TLSv1.2"
    }
}

ssl-config {
    logger = "com.typesafe.sslconfig.akka.util.AkkaLoggerBridge"
}
```

i've added:

```
println(system.settings.config)
```

but i get a result without stream section

Can you assist?

Comment: Is your `myService.jar` an uber jar?

Comment: How is the config loaded? Is it taken care of by the `ActorSystem` or are you doing it yourself?

Comment: To be sure, what's the result of `ls -l /opt/myService/conf/application.conf`?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4284 Sep 12 16:33 /opt/myservice/conf/application.conf

Comment: if i run it with no arguments, i get the same error. it is a fat jar indeed

Comment: try: `java -jar ./myService.jar -Dconfig.resource=/opt/myservice/conf/application.conf -Dconfig.file=/opt/myService/conf/application.conf`, it should throw another exception if system properties are correctly set

Comment: same exception.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with the way you define the system properties, I was hoping to trigger this exception: https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/config/src/main/java/com/typesafe/config/DefaultConfigLoadingStrategy.java#L38
From your code, try printing the value of the system `config.file` to ensure it is correctly defined

Comment: please look at my edit

Comment: I meant to print the system *property* `config.file`, not the config itself, although I'm curious to know what kind of stuff are loaded in your config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the `java` command line is:

```
java [options] -jar filename [args]
```

This ordering matters: you must set any options before the `-jar` option.

So in your case:

```
java -Dconfig.file=/opt/myService/conf/application.conf -jar ./myService.jar
```